# Why doesnt ngTable accept my dataset?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have a simple piece of data that I'm trying to test with Ng-Table. I followed the example on ng-table but I'm assuming dataset is expecting a promise instead of an array. The only difference Im seeing is how Im handling $scope.

My example works if I put the data variable on scope and dont pass it to tableParams from my js file but then I lose the functionality of filters.

Ng-Table example: 
   https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/examples-old/demo15.html

My Code 
HTML

```
<div ng-app="Pulse">
<div ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <table ng-table="main.groupTable" class="table" show-filter="true">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data"
            <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
                {{user.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Js

```
var app = angular.module("Pulse", ['ngTable'])
   .controller("MainController", MainController );

 function MainController ($scope, NgTableParams) {
    var self = this;
    var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50}];
    $scope.groupTable = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: data});
 };
```

Comment: your variable names don't match.  in your JS you have `$scope.groupTable` but in the HTML you have `$scope.tableParams`.  also, referencing `$scope` at all in the HTML is not correct.  Try `ng-table="groupTable"` instead.

Comment: yea I tried switching, it to your suggestion but it still doesnt render. I tried putting in a debugger and checking groupTable the variable $data is empty by the time it loads on the page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently, ng-table use 'data' property instead of 'dataset'. I guess they've just forgot to update the documentation. So just write:

```
$scope.groupTable = new NgTableParams({}, { data: data});
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

New version(1.x) is using 'dataset' property but the old version(0.8.3 tested) is using 'data' property